# How to vertically align middle float left and right objects ? without exact line height property

Tags: html, css, css-float, vertical-alignment

Ok here the problem

http://jsfiddle.net/vT4YT/

```
 <table><tr><td><div></div><div></div></td></tr></table>
```

Now you see that the option and that row text is not vertically aligned middle

I can put inside a table but it really really increases the written junk code

Aren't there any more proper solution when using float left and right ?

Thank you

And here what i mean

**And please do not post answers with exact-line-height such as 120px or put another table inside td**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `margin-top` considered "exact-line-height"?  http://jsfiddle.net/KCvfZ/1/.

```
    .FloatLeft
    {
        margin-top:15px;  
        overflow: hidden;
        float: left;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for answer but yes :D I also came to accept that either exact positioning or table usage is a must.